# Can I run cli commands in magento 2 through button or action or route?

Tags: command, magento2.4.1

I want to run magento cli commands in magento 2.4.1 through button or action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that is an extremely insecure practice, you can.

The *fast way* would be to pass directly through the `Shell` object:

```
use Magento\Framework\Shell;
use Magento\Framework\Shell\CommandRenderer;

// put in your constructor
public function __construct() {
    $this->shell = new Shell(new CommandRenderer());
}

// put in your action execute method
public function execute() {
    $command = 'php bin/magento setup:upgrade';
    $this->shell->execute($command);
}
```

A *cleaner* way would be to find the command implementation in the source code and execute it in your action/button. The CLI commands are classes which extend the `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` class. Once called, such class performs the code inside the `execute()` method.

Thus, you can use:

```
// put in your constructor
public function __construct(
    <Vendor>\<Module>\<PathToCommandClass> $command
) {
    $this->command = $command;
}

// in your action
public function execute() {
    $command->execute();
}
```

where `$command` is passed in the action constructor as a dependency.